# select those records having specific value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to select those records having specific value in one of the column. Consider below example :

```
NAME    VALUETEST

rec1    val1
rec2    val1
rec3    val1
rec1    test123
rec1    test1234
rec2    test1234
```

Here i wish to select only those records having valuetest column value as val1,test123 and test1234 only, i.e rec1. I have tried below simple select queries but it is not giving me the desired results
Query : `select * from temp  where valuetest = all ('val1','test123','test1234');`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
select name from temp where valuetest = 'val1'
intersect
select name from temp where valuetest = 'test123'
intersect
select name from temp where valuetest = 'test1234'
```

And if there are more columns that you want selected from table than just name, run:

```
select * from temp where name in(
    select name from temp where valuetest = 'val1'
    intersect
    select name from temp where valuetest = 'test123'
    intersect
    select name from temp where valuetest = 'test1234')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer your answer seems to give me the correct result, but i was wondering what is wrong with my query?

Comment: A single value can't be X, Y, and Z, at the same time. A single value can, however, be higher or lower than X, Y, and Z. That is when ALL/ANY is typically used. See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php

Comment: Another way to look at it is: you want values of "name" on a table where that name value has on at least one row a value of valuetest that is "X", "Y" on ANOTHER ROW (NOT THE SAME ROW), and "Z" on ANOTHER ROW (NOT THE SAME ROW).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM temp
WHERE valuetest IN ('val1','test123','test1234')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

It will retrieve all `NAME`s that have a matching for `val1`, `test123` and `test1234`.

If you actually need all rows and not just the names you should use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, COUNT(*)
    FROM temp
    WHERE valuetest IN ('val1','test123','test1234')
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) USING(name);
```

Also, this approach will scan the table only twice regardless of the number of values from the condition (`'val1','test123','test1234',...`)

Comment: but it will eliminate any other rows from each name that have all 3 of those values, and which might be of interest. Granted, very little detail was given in the question, but that is a limitation.

Comment: I agree, but given the context, the only value of interest seems to be `NAME`. Either way my query can be easily adjusted to fit this request as well. Thanks for pointing it out (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Does this query give you the desired results?

```
select *
from temp
where valuetest in ('val1', 'test123', 'test1234');
```

Comment: your answer gives me all the records which have any one of the valuestest, whereas i want only those records which has all the 3 valuetest value.

Answer (score 0):

select * from temp  where valuetest **IN** ('val1','test123','test1234');

or use can use

select * from temp  where valuetest = **ANY**('val1','test123','test1234');

Use **Any** in place of **All** because for **All** its tries to match all the three values for a single record

Comment: your answer gives me all the records which have any one of the valuestest, whereas i want only those records which has all the 3 valuetest value.